# How to calculate the "training dataset error" in Encog Machine Learning Framework

Tags: c#, encog

I am using `CalculateGradients()` ([source](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/8d0540a3ab0fd3ff0b4310108d33ac51d63c97a5/encog-core-cs/Neural/Networks/Training/Propagation/Propagation.cs#L278)) on a test dataset (30% of my data). See code below.

The goal is to get the error on the `testingDataSet`, using the parameters calculated by `trainingDataSet` (70% of my data).

My question: is `CalculateGradients()` independent? (thus just allowing me to calculate the error as intended), or is it adding another iteration to the shared `network` thus spoiling the isolation of the "training dataset"?

Source code for `Iteration()` here: [source](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/8d0540a3ab0fd3ff0b4310108d33ac51d63c97a5/encog-core-cs/Neural/Networks/Training/Propagation/Propagation.cs#L182).

Code:

```
public void Train(BasicNetwork network, IMLDataSet trainingDataSet, IMLDataSet testingDataSet)
{
    var trainPropagation = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingDataSet);
    var testPropagation = new ResilientPropagation(network, testingDataSet);

    var epoch = 1;
    do
    {
        trainPropagation.Iteration();

        // !!! Trying to calculate the error on `testingDataSet` using the parameters from `trainPropagation`
        testPropagation.CalculateGradients();

        Console.WriteLine($"Epoch #{epoch}, Train error: {trainPropagation.Error}, Test error: {testPropagation.Error}" );

        if (double.IsNaN(trainPropagation.Error))
            throw new Exception("Train error was NaN");                

        epoch++;

    } while (trainPropagation.Error > _maxError);

}
```